# AWS lambda's function URL without API Gateway in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that is invoked with API Gateway.
The function is working using the GET method with this code:

```golang
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    // add code here

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: request.Body, StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)
}
```

I have this `event.APIGatewayProxyRequest` and `GET` method. But when I try to migrate the URL to a [Function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html), I have nothing similar to set the `GET` method. How was the URL supposed to know which method to use in the POSTMAN? and...

Do we have an equivalent for `event.APIGatewayProxyRequest` to do the request?

When I invoke it with URL, I got a `502` **BAD GATEWAY** error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The AWS event for Lambda Function URL is [`events.LambdaFunctionURLRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events#LambdaFunctionURLRequest) and the [related types](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/main/events/lambda_function_urls.go).

So your handler signature should look like:

```
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, request events.LambdaFunctionURLRequest) (events.LambdaFunctionURLResponse, error) {
    // add code here
    return events.LambdaFunctionURLResponse{Body: request.Body, StatusCode: 200}, nil
}
```

Once you create the URL of your Lambda, the caller (e.g. Postman) can specify whatever HTTP method, which you can access inside your handler with:

```
// request is LambdaFunctionURLRequest
request.RequestContext.HTTP.Method
```